# Linux + send wall message only to the specific user

Tags: linux, users

As all know, we can send broadcast message to all users on a Linux machine.

But how to send message only to the specific user?

For example:

```
#who

rodegc  pts/1        2015-05-04 04:23 (10.4.72.1)
dwwar   pts/3        2015-05-03 00:56 (10.4.72.2)
tzcsar  pts/5        2015-05-03 22:32 (10.4.72.6)
.
.
.
.
.
```

In this case how to send broadcast message only to the user rodegc?

**FROM MAN PAGE:**

```
 WALL(1)                       Linux User's Manual                      WALL(1)

 NAME
 wall -- send a message to everybodyגs terminal.

 SYNOPSIS
 wall [-n] [ message ]
```

From the man page, I can't see any option to send to a specific user.

Comment: Also from the man page `man wall`: 
SEE ALSO
     mesg(1), talk(1), write(1), shutdown(8)
. Similar or related tools are often mentioned in the See Also section.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With `write`:

```
write <user> 
Some text goes here
CTRL-D (eof)
```

Alternative:

```
echo "Some text goes here" | write <user>
```

See `man write`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent receiving writes? just in case an HILARIOUS coworker decides to `yes | write badp`

Comment: Oh, that's `mesg n`